# Installing clang_complete on macOs

Tags: c++, c, macos, vim, clang

I am trying to get clang_complete to run on macOS preinstalled vim. 
This is what I have done.

1. Installed PlugInstall
2. Tested it with other Plugins if it works and it worked just fine with COC(another autocompletion tool but without C support )
3. placed this bit of code into my `.vimrc` file:

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')                                           

"Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'} //This worked fine 
Plug 'rip-rip/clang_complete'  //This installed just fine but doesnt work

call plug#end()
let g:clang_library_path='/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libclang.dylib' //Path to libclang
```

4. Now I opened vim and ran `:PlugInstall`, which worked just fine
5. Opened a .c file and the file doesnt even open. Just a blank grey screen from the theme I am using and I have to force quit my terminal.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `:CocInstall coc-clangd`, this will use clangd to do completion. You need to install clangd first: https://clangd.llvm.org/installation.html